# Scraping a Specific Element in a Class Name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and am trying to practice as much as I can. So currently, I would like to scrape some data from a betting site: https://online.singaporepools.com/sportsbook/en/home

What I want to get is the first match name that is happening tonight. The HTML code is as  follows:

```
<span class="event-list__event-name" 
data-reactid=".2.1:$1529510400000.1.0.1.$14027.2.0">
    <a 
    href="/sportsbook/en/Event/14027/football/world/w-cup/denmark-vs-australia" 
    data-reactid=".2.1:$1529510400000.1.0.1.$14027.2.0.0">Denmark vs Australia</a>
</span>
```

Currently, my code is as such:

> Set allrowofdata = IE.document.GetElementsByClassName("event-list__event-name")(1)
>
> Dim myValue As String
>
> myValue = allrowofdata.innerhtml

What this gives me when I run it is: a href="/sportsbook/en/Event/14029/football/world/w-cup/france-vs-peru" data-reactid=".2.1:$1529510400000.1.0.1.$14029.3.0.3.0.0">France vs Peru

However, what I want is just the "France vs Peru" element. I've tried changing the code to

> Set allrowofdata = IE.document.GetElementsByClassName("event-list__event-name")(1).getElementsByTagName("data-reactid")

but it doesn't work, I get an error message saying: Object doesn't support this property or method.

I don't know how to work around the data-reactID as I've never accounted it before. Hope you guys can help me out, I'll really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `myValue = allrowofdata.innerText`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you so much! Can't believe I did not know that.